# WooCommerce WP_Query returns empty after adding a new "tax_query" array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a custom PHP that will return the output to an AJAX call from a WordPress site.

The basic call to WP_Query works, and I got the products show correctly. This would be the $args object I pass to it:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => $itemsPerPage, // '12'
    'paged'                 => $page,
    'tax_query'             => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field'         => 'term_id',
            'terms'         => 304,
            'operator'      => 'IN' // 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_visibility',
            'field'         => 'slug',
            'terms'         => 'exclude-from-catalog',
            'operator'      => 'NOT IN'
        ),
    )
);
```

The thing is that after declaring this, I check the query parameters to see if any filters were sent. When required, I do this:

```
 $arrayQuery = [];
 $arrayQuery["taxonomy"] = $taxonomy;
 $arrayQuery["field"] = "term_id";
 $arrayQuery["terms"] = $arrayTerms;
 $arrayQuery["operator"] = "IN"; 

 array_push($args["tax_query"], $arrayQuery);
```

After some loops, the resulting $args is the following (output from print_r()):

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => product
    [post_status] => publish
    [ignore_sticky_posts] => 1
    [posts_per_page] => 12
    [paged] => 1
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => product_cat
                    [field] => term_id
                    [terms] => 304
                    [operator] => IN
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => product_visibility
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => exclude-from-catalog
                    [operator] => NOT IN
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => pa_expedicion
                    [field] => term_id
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 469
                        )

                    [operator] => IN
                )
        )
)
```

With this object, the result is empty.

After some debug, I got the SQL that is run on MySQL, which is this one (**don't waste time reading yet**):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)  
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id)
WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (43,44,47,94,96,304) 
  AND 
  wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (7)
            ) 
  AND 
  tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (469)
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12
```

The thing is that after some tests on phpMyAdmin, I managed to get it to return the 6 items that match the filters.

I had to comment two lines:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)  
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id)
WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
--  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (43,44,47,94,96,304) 
--  AND 
  wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM wp_term_relationships
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (7)
            ) 
  AND 
  tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (469)
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12
```

But that doesn't make any sense, does it?

The products returned need to be in those categories.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I don't understand why adding another condition makes this to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know what I was doing wrong.

When debugging on phpMyAdmin, I assummed that the 6 products returned where from the categories I was looking.

It happens that this "pa_expedicion" attribute is shared with products from another category too.

None of the products on the categories "43,44,47,94,96,304" have a "term_id" 469.

I tested the PHP script changing it to 467, which some products have, and the WP_Query call is now returning the products as intended.